# Reporting Services (SharePoint Mode) parameters on top?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to move the parameters panel from the right to the top?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, No you cannot do that.
I usually use SSRS report with Microsoft dynamics crm.
There we have separate report area and it open as a webpage.
Sometimes there is an use case, I have to open SSRS report in a frame or in web resource(HTML page).

In such cases, i usually hack HTML and then hide/show div/class to show parameter or any other info. But please note this is an unsupported way.

Summary: No I do not think so, we have any supported way to do this.
Reason SSRS report are reports and focus is on reporting rather than UI.

Answer (score 1):

I also suspect that this kind of customization is rather not possible without any major hack. The only thing I managed to find is possible option to [add custom css file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/customize-style-sheets-for-html-viewer-and-report-manager?view=sql-server-2014) to HTML viewer but with this You should be able only to updated the top bar :(.

Maybe this could be a good argument to try to move forward for example to Power BI :).